# What is the functionality of the clickhouse-copier service?

Tags: clickhouse

Clickhouse-copier for copying data from one cluster to another.

Examples of the config files that i need to create for the copier

Clickhouse-copier for copying data from one cluster to another.

Examples of the config files that i need to create for the copier

Comment: clickhouse-copier is now obsolete, no longer supported, and has a new home - https://github.com/ClickHouse/copier. You may find all the instructions and config files there.